# docker build keep building wrong architecture

Tags: docker, dockerfile

The following Dockerfile keeps building for wrong architecture:

Note I can not use buildx as I need to install specific tools for different architectures

arm64/Dockerfile

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

# Download arm64 specifict tools

FROM golang:1.17.2 as build

WORKDIR /source

COPY src/go.mod ./
COPY src/go.sum ./
RUN go mod download

COPY src/ ./
RUN env GOOS=linux GOARCH=arm64 go build -o /app
```

docker build:

```
docker build \
--target build -t $CURRENT_REGISTRY/mycontainer:arm64 \
-f ./docker/$ARCH/Dockerfile .
```

docker inspect:

```
docker inspect manifest $CURRENT_REGISTRY/mycontainer:arm64
```

Output:(should be arm64 and not amd64)?

```
 ...
 "Architecture": "amd64",
        "Os": "linux",
        "Size": 323727784,
        "VirtualSize": 323727784,
 ...
```

Comment: https://developer.arm.com/documentation/102475/0100/Multi-architecture-images Any idea from this?

Comment: Thanks, turns out I can actually use "docker buildx build", one for each platform and combine each using docker manifest create.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `docker buildx build` and not just `build` on each platform. Then use docker `docker manifest create`.